# Error al guardar datos de uno a muchos

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, postgresql-9.3

estoy realizando una aplicación , mi back esta hecha en spring-boot , el problema es que quiero guardar un "equipment" que esta relacionado de uno a muchos con "EquipmentParameter".
codigo de Equipment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipment")
public class Equipment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastupdate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean status = true;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = MasterDetail.class, optional = false)
    private MasterDetail typeEquipment;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Substation.class, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Substation substation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EquipmentParameter> equipmentParameters=new ArrayList();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Photo> photos=new ArrayList();

    public void addEquipmentParameter(EquipmentParameter e) {
        this.getEquipmentParameters();
        if (this.equipmentParameters.size()>1 && !this.equipmentParameters.contains(e)) {
            this.equipmentParameters.add(e);
            e.setEquipment(this);
        }
    }


}
```

Codigo de EquipmentParameter:

```
   @Entity
@Table
public class EquipmentParameter {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Equipment.class)
private Equipment equipment;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = MasterDetail.class,optional = false)
private MasterDetail masterDetail;
private String value;}
```

El Json que envio a mi backend:

> equipmentParameters: [{value: "wdwd", masterDetail: {id: 2}}, {value:
>   "wdwd", masterDetail: {id: 3}},…] 0: {value: "wdwd", masterDetail:
>   {id: 2}} 1: {value: "wdwd", masterDetail: {id: 3}} 2: {value: "wdwd",
>   masterDetail: {id: 4}} 3: {value: "wdwd", masterDetail: {id: 5}} 4:
>   {value: "2", masterDetail: {id: 6}} substation: {id: 2} typeEquipment:
>   {id: 1, name: "ACOMETIDA", code: "EQ", value: "AC"} photos:
>   [{fileName: "59f430a2-b39f-4990-b93f-1e9f90dc8f48Captura.PNG",…}]

El error que me muestra por consola es:

```
        insert 
    into
        EquipmentParameter
        (equipment_id, masterDetail_id, value) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        EquipmentParameter
        (equipment_id, masterDetail_id, value) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m ERROR: el valor null para la columna «equipment_id» viola la restricción not null
  Detail: La fila que falla contiene (8, wdwd, null, 2).


org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: el valor null para la columna «equipment_id» viola la restricción not null
```

no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: En tu base de datos declaraste tus ID´s como tipo SERIAL?

Comment: no nada , eso  no se resolveria con la anotacion @GenerateValue?

Comment: En teoria, no he usado PostgreSQL pero al parecer requieres que tus ID´s sean tipo SERIAL para poder usar el GenerationType.IDENTITY, checa esta liga https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-serial-column-hibernate-identity/